# wp_mail encode ’ in &rsquo; in subject

Tags: wp-mail, encoding

I create a function to send mail (in french) for custom post, it's work but subject is encoding in html.

I do this :

```
$get_title = get_the_title($ID);
wp_mail("me@my.com","new article : ".$get_title,"The message is OK with é è à",$headers);
```

My email source is like this

```
X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.14 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
```

I get this subject « new article : it`&rsquo;`s not ok ».

Answer (score 1):

It's look OK with : [html_entity_decode](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.html-entity-decode.php)

```
wp_mail("me@my.com","new article : ".html_entity_decode($get_title),"The message is OK with é è à",$headers);
```

Not so good, another try :

```
wp_mail("me@my.com","new article : ".$post->post_title,"The message is OK with é è à",$headers);
```